# Java Microphone Recording

Tags: java, random, input, microphone, noise

I have a little weird question.
The project is sound wave recognition, i have the neural networks up and running and as it turns out the thing i payed the least attention turned out to be a pain in the ass.

It's a java application that needs to capture sound for now via a computer microphone, i followed oracle documentation for sound capture and here is my code very simple now because the more complex one appeared to be a bust!

```
public class Main extends JFrame{
//audio prop.
private static int SampleRate=8000;
private static int BitsPerSample=16;
private static int Channel=1;
private static boolean signed=true;
private static boolean isBigEndian=true;

private static byte[] buffer;
static AudioFormat format;
static DataLine.Info info;
static TargetDataLine line;

private static XYSeries series;
private static XYSeriesCollection xyCollection;
private static JFreeChart chart; 

public void call(ChartPanel panel){     
    add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException {
    ChartPanel chartPanel;
    format= new AudioFormat(SampleRate, BitsPerSample,Channel , signed, isBigEndian);
    info= new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
    if(!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info))
    {
        System.out.print("Line not supported");
    }
    else
    {
        /*
         * chart declarations
         */
        series= new XYSeries("Audio");
        xyCollection=new XYSeriesCollection();
        xyCollection.addSeries(series);
        chart= ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Microphone Recording", "X","Y",  xyCollection);
        chartPanel=new ChartPanel(chart);
        Main obj= new Main();
        obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        obj.setSize(640,480);
        obj.call(chartPanel);
        obj.setVisible(true);
        line= (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        line.open(format);
        line.start(); 
        buffer= new byte[line.getBufferSize()];
        ByteBuffer bb= ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        while(line.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)>0){
                for(int i=0;i<buffer.length-1;i++){
                    series.add(i,buffer[i]);
                }
        }

    }

}
```

Now here is what happens, i get constant input of a random noise even when there is no sound!
If you are trying to tell me that that is because i haven't combined the data according to the 16 bits per sample format, it is not it, i have tried that also.

So the question is what the heck this code registers because it's not sound, and the oracle documentation specifically says that this is the way to get a handle of the mic.

And what is the correct way to do it obviously? 
Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I'm on the fly on this project im c# developer so be gentle!
:)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of *jfreechart* do you use? With 1.0.0 I had to add a few arguments to `createXYLineChart(...)`.

If I run your code I can see that your Y-axis' scale adjusts dynamically. From ~-8 to ~8 if no mic is connected (with random blips). From ~-125 to ~125 if there is one (with a sinusoidal curve). Isn't there some noise on every line? Maybe it looks less impressive if you apply an appropiate fixed scale to your Y-axis.

What makes me wonder is that the graph doesn't change if I actually speak into the mic.

Comment: I'm using 1.0.23 jcommon and 1.0.19 jfreechart.
The thing is you get no change even if you speak to the microphone, i will try and apply scaling but i don't think that is the solution.

Comment: OK, with 1.0.19 it compiles as given. Now also the graph changes if I speak into the mic. But it doesn't get more than ~-140 to ~140. No matter how loud I speak. (My wife was already asking what I am doing here :-) Mh...I don't have any further idea atm.

Comment: Thanks For the effort anyway, even high frequency whistles which have high energy over the frequency spectrum doesn't seem to have any effect.